# AddForce to local transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make a game to put my relatively new coding knowledge to test. I figured I learn a lot quicker by just doing things and seeing what happens. I'm currently working on a plane and the last couple of days I made a functional camera system (to rotate around the player based on the mouse) and some animations of the plane. I'm currently trying to create a movement system in which the down key rotates the player up. I noticed however that my AddForce function doesn't do what I want it to do. I'd like the plane to move in the Z axis depending on the current rotation of said plane instead of it just heading into the Z angle of the world.

I'm currently working on this snippet:

```
 //Acceleration
 if (gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && playerRb.velocity.z > -349)
 {
     playerRb.AddRelativeForce(0, 0, -playerSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
 }
 else if (gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && playerRb.velocity.z < -349)
 {
     playerRb.velocity = new Vector3(playerRb.velocity.x, playerRb.velocity.y, -350);
 }
 //

 //Movement
 //Up/down controls
 if (gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
 {
     transform.Rotate((0.07f * playerSpeed) * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
 }
```

As you can see I already tried AddRelativeForce as another topic mentioned but that doesn't seem to work for me. The moment it hits an edge it just falls down into the abyss regardless of it's rotation.

Additionally, I was considering using another AddForce function on the rotate as it doesn't leave the ground (considering it keeps hitting the floor with its tail), is there any way to apply a force on an object from a specific position/angle? (such as the front of the plane).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason your plane is acting strange is not because of your addrelative force call -- it's because you are setting velocity.      `playerRb.velocity = new Vector3(playerRb.velocity.x, playerRb.velocity.y, -350);` assigns the velocity to push you -350 in the world's z axis, which probably isn't what you want. Velocity is in the global space. Remove that and see what happens.

On a more general note, If you're using physics, try to use only forces and torquees. Using `transform.Rotate` to change a rigidbody's rotation while physics is active will just make your life difficult, and make the rigidbody do strange things. I do change the velocity of rigidbodies sometimes, but not in every frame. I just don't know enough about physics to mess with velocities that way.

Also, make sure you're doing these things in a `FixedUpdate` function, since that is where input that affects physics is supposed to be checked.

Comment: Oh that actually makes a lot of sense. I'd like to have a maximum speed, hence that line but I can see the folly in that. Cause if the force is applied every frame while the throttle is up it just keeps on going. Is there any way to cap the amount of force being applied? Just lowering the value on the addrelativeforce function?

Also I'll take a look at fixedupdate, I saw stuff on it before but I could probably use it!

Comment: You can still have a maximum speed -- just make sure that the `playerRb.magnitude` value of your velocity vector is not above a certain point! The magnitude is the same as the size of a vector. I would do this by checking the vector's magnitude. If it's over your max speed, then normalize the vector (get the direction, basically) and then multiply it by your max speed again. This will allow players to change their direction while going max speed.